Rocket equation non-constant gravity
I am currently trying to teach myself differential equations and wondered about the following problem.
You have an object (a rocket of constant mass $m_r$) and initial velocity $v_0$ that tries to leave earth. Now I would like to model position $x(t)$ and velocity $v(t)$ of the rocket considering that the gravitational pull of the earth decreases the further the rocket is away from the earth.
By my understanding, you can in general start with $F = ma = -G mM / x^2$ with $m$ and $M$ (mass of the earth), $x$ being the distance to the earth surface.
Given this on gets $a(t) = x''(t) = -G M /(r+x)^2$ with $r$ as the earth radius and $x''$ being the second derivative of rocket location. Given this, one could solve for the position $x(t)$ and velocity $x'(t)$ considering the initial conditions. Does this make sense (?)
If that approach is okay, then I should get a similar answer as stated in this thread.
I set up just a little python code to model x(t) and v(t). One can actually check that 11900 m/s seems to be the escape velocity.
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Constants
G = 6.67430e-11  # Gravitational constant (m^3 kg^-1 s^-2)
M = 5.972e24     # Mass of the Earth (kg)
R = 6.371e6      # Radius of the Earth (m)
v0 = 1000        # Initial velocity (m/s)

# Initial conditions
r0 = R
initial_conditions = [r0, v0]

# Define the system of ODEs
def rocket_dynamics(t, y):
    r, v = y
    drdt = v
    dvdt = -G * M / r**2
    return [drdt, dvdt]

# Time span for the simulation
t_span = (0, 1000)  # Simulate for 1000 seconds
t_eval = np.linspace(t_span[0], t_span[1], 1000)  # Evaluation points

# Solve the ODE
solution = solve_ivp(rocket_dynamics, t_span, initial_conditions, t_eval=t_eval)

# Extract the results
r = solution.y[0]
v = solution.y[1]
t = solution.t

# Plot the results
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
plt.subplot(2, 1, 1)
plt.plot(t, r)
plt.xlabel('Time (s)')
plt.ylabel('Distance from Earth center (m)')
plt.title('Rocket Distance vs Time')

plt.subplot(2, 1, 2)
plt.plot(t, v)
plt.xlabel('Time (s)')
plt.ylabel('Velocity (m/s)')
plt.title('Rocket Velocity vs Time')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()


BTW, as I explain here: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/48616/16685 you should avoid using G (when possible). You can get GM values for the major Solar System barycentres here: https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/astro_par.html
